# Bluetooth icon missing from iMac. How do I connect wireless keyboard

Tags: macos, imac, bluetooth, system-settings

How can I connect wireless keyboard to iMac when Bluetooth icon missing from system preferences?  I bought a refurbished computer and have not been able to connect due to missing Bluetooth icon needed to connect wireless keyboard

Comment: The bluetooth module on you iMac might be missing or damaged.

Answer (score 2):

To setup Bluetooth keyboard:

1. Go to System Preferences app → Keyboard → Keyboard.
2. Click on **Set Up Bluetooth Keyboard...** button shown at the bottom.

[image]

Now, the Bluetooth icon may have been removed from System Preferences app.

[image]

To get the Bluetooth icon back again:

1. With System Preferences app, click View → Customize... in the Menu bar.

[image]

2. Select the checkbox besides the Bluetooth icon and tap **Done** button shown in the toolbar.

[image]

3. Voila! Bluetooth icon is back again in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: There is no Bluetooth icon under system preferences

Comment: @Nolap Did you follow Nimesh's directions to customize the System Preferences?